# run a script once a service stops

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

i want to create a windows Service that will do the following

> ON Custom_Service start:

1. Make sure "Spooler" service is stopped if not continue else go
   to 3.
2. kill the "Spooler" process.
3. Delete some files.
4. Start the "Spooler" service.

> ON Custom_Service Stop:

1. check "Spooler" service status if it's Running continue else go
   to 3.
2. kill the "Spooler" process.
3. Delete some files.

> P.S. i am familiar with the Powershell scripting language

- the new Custom_service should be always running

i know how to do all the scripting, but the part that i don't know is how to run a part of a command when you stop a service, i don't know if i am making my self clear, may be another approach is to run a script before ending the service proccess

Comment: i suggest you to learn PowerShell :) is like cmd with script+.net

Comment: i know PowerShell but i don't know .net at all

Comment: Dear Asaf , can you please send me the code by a url either C# or powershell and i will try to modify it to meet my needs, thanks

Comment: sure let me find that code and i will write for you that the part of c# and the powershell

Comment: join to chat when you can:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101670/powershellservice

Comment: i am inside the room but since i dont have 20 reputations i can not talk .. here is my skype, add me if you like : vaghig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it took 3 parts of that:

1. The Create of windwos service with c#:

Enter this in the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
namespace RunPowerShell
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        // the thread that will work
        Thread th;

        // Varible for stop thread
        bool RequestStop;
        const int SecondToWait = 5;
        const int miliToSec    = 1000;

        public Service1()
        {
            // Init
            InitializeComponent();

            // Create Thread by LINQ
            th = new Thread(() => PowerShellRun());

            // Init as start
            RequestStop = false;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            // Log file that start Serivce
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\tryService\Log.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine("Start: " + System.DateTime.Now);
            }

            // Thread Start
            th.Start();


        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {

            // Log file that Stop Serivce
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\tryService\Log.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine("Stop: " + System.DateTime.Now);
            }

            // Stop the thread 
            RequestStop = true;

            // Wait for the thread will be stop
            Thread.Sleep(SecondToWait * miliToSec);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Your Program in that Service
        /// </summary>
        public void PowerShellRun()
        {
            while (!RequestStop)
            {

                // Your progarm here such as run Powershell
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\tryService\Log.txt", true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine("InProgress: " + System.DateTime.Now);
                }

                //Process.Start(@"powershell C:\tryService\Untitled2.ps1");

                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = @"& 'C:\tryService\MyPSExecute.ps1'";
                //startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                //startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();



                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(SecondToWait * 1000);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

After you put it in your service
Build it then it will create you file *Name*.exe

Take this file and put in someFolder that url "C:\tryService"

2. Create Bat file that will register that SericeFile to the Computer 
   Services...

Register.Bat: (You do it once after you can delete this file)

```
sc.exe delete ProcessSpooler
sc.exe create ProcessSpooler binPath= "C:\tryService\RunPowerShell.exe" DisplayName= "Process Spooler" start= auto
```

3. Your powershell File that called in my project "MyPSExecute.ps1"

   you put then all in the same folder

Comment: Error 1 The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

Comment: lol create a new windows service without rename it wait i will upload it

Comment: srry for late. my mom came 
link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByHeKSxfEZ7qRzl6LWpmQ3A1WlE/view?usp=sharing

@user2840250

Comment: thanks, it is working .. i will test it and get back to you maybe tomorrow, thanks again

Comment: Really sorry for late, my mom came... need to make her a coffee :)

all you need to change is the script:
step:

run once the bat file for have the service register(it will start automatic on computer startup) and then change the ps file

Comment: btw skype: asaf12100